# How to read a game memory on android

Tags: android, memory-management

I want to make something that you can compare to an esp for an android game, but nothing commercial or anything, just want to experiment. I want to know the location of lets say ghosts from pacman, or the bal in pinball, or even airplanes in a flying game.

How do I start with this? I've read some things about how memory works and some functions to actually get it. But I dont know how to FIND the addresses. Also I dont know how to use them in a if statement for example.

For find the memory on Windows is simple on windows with cheatengine programm but on android i have no idea.
Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To develop your own android game you need to learn java or kotlin programming language firstly.

If you want to automize an app which is not your own `read it's license agreements and don't do something which is not allowed`. You can checkout programms which are used for `testautomisation`. I can recomment `NOX emulator` which can also automise clicks or `Appium` if you need more complex automisation. Appium needs programming skills as well though.
There are also a lot of other options for (test)automisation of all kind of apps/programms.